# How do I combine data from two DateTime columns (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, concatenation

Using SQL Server 2005, I am working with a database which has two columns to keep track of what is essentially a single DateTime (and I can't for the life of my figure out why anyone would ever think this is a good idea).

Basically, one column, let's call it OrderDate, contains a DateTime like this: 2008-02-29 00:00:00.000, and the other column, OrderTime, has one like this: 1900-01-01 11:15:00.000

So, now I am forced to combine these two whenever I want to display the entire date and time in one place. This is easy from a UI perspective, but how would I do this at the DB level? I want to be able to write a query finds a DATEDIFF between the combined date and time from these two columns and compares it to another DateTime value.

Ex:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, CompletionTime, OrderTime) AS TurnAroundTime FROM SomeRecord
```

The problem with the above being of course that OrderTime's date component is 1900-01-01, resulting in a *slightly* skewed result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "OrderDate + OrderTime" in SQL to create "OrderDateTime". Or define a computed column.

The SQL standard supports standard addition on datetimes, I'm sure, and SQL Server implements it.

[There is an example in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178565.aspx)

Comment: I'd also add, though, that he should be absolutely sure these two columns will never have a "piece" of a date or time as well as a time or date, respectively. For example, can he be sure he'd never see '1992-01-01 11:15:00.000' in OrderTime?  In which case, I'd recommend using some calculation using DATEPART() in the calc'd column.

Answer (score 2):

Create a computed column that adds them together

```
  Alter Table TableName Add CompleteDate as DateOnlyColName + TimeOnlyColName
```

to make sure that errant time data in the DateOnlyColName is not inadvertenetly added in, use this instead...

```
  Alter Table TableName Add CompleteDate as 
         DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, DateOnlyColName), 0) + 
                      TimeOnlyColName
```